# Idiom/Phrase to fight someone else's war?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Like, people made to fight for a war that was not needed. But they are made to do it under someone else's influence.

*Edit

Apologies for not being more specific. Yes, I would say being used as ***canon fodder*** to fight wars on behalf of someone's else motives.

Like being fooled to fight saying it is good for the group/nation. But down the line it turns out it was not needed.

Comment: Depending on your perspective, you might say that *all* wars are "not needed". And it's practically a truism that the people who decide to start wars are rarely likely to be among those killed on the battlefield. Those who do the (real or figurative) fighting on the front line might be called ***foot soldiers*** (***cannon fodder***, to the jaundiced). Or ***civilian volunteers / mercenaries*** if they do it willingly for kicks / justice / money.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah... *cannon fodder* was my first thought, but now I see that it is in your comment...you gonna post a real answer? If not, I will post, but I am waiting for clarification of the Q

Comment: Hello Shad...could you please edit to include more detail and a little research? The bit about "unneeded war" is problematic, as this is a political issue, and hence POB..However, I gave .+1 for the idea

Comment: What is a "someone's else war"?

Comment: What do you mean by a war that's not needed? Are you talking about something like people being drafted to fight in the Viet Nam War, even though they felt the war was unnecessary?

Comment: Yes you guys are correct. That's what was my thoughts were. Thank you again.

Comment: Example: when Bush said the US was going to war because of weapons of mass destruction (which turned out not to have existed, other than in Bush's imagination).  Here's one way of expressing your idea: *Joe was **suckered** into enlisting, thanks to Bush's lies.*

Comment: I have just cast the deciding vote to re-open your post...consider doing a bit of research to avoid another close

Comment: Again, what is a "someone's else war"?

Comment: @HotLicks It's kind of like "someone else's problem" i.e. [SEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_else%27s_problem)  BTW, I fixed the offending bit in the title

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ But what is an "else war"???

Comment: I fixed that typo...we should be good to go now. Or maybe it is a war between Ls and Js or Ks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"To fight someone else's'*  war" sounds a little like ...

***proxy war/fight/fighter***

> A proxy war is an armed conflict between two states or non-state actors which act on the instigation or on behalf of **other parties that are not directly involved in the hostilities**
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_war)

However,

> If you describe soldiers as ***cannon fodder***, you mean that they are not considered important by their officers and are sent into war without their leaders worrying if they die.
> [Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cannon-fodder)

Unfortunately, this appears to address only the " *made to do it under someone else's influence*." bit of your question. but not i.e "an unneeded war"

I am struggling to find **a single phrase** that applies to both concepts....